# How to add scroll bar in wxRadioBox?

Tags: c++, scrollbar, wxwidgets

I am using wxRadioBox to display multiple names with radio buttons, but I need a scroll bar for it? How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a wxScrolledWindow?

Answer (score 2):

wxRadioBox doesn't provide the scroll feature.

You can use several [wxRadioButton](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_radio_button.html)  instead.

Create all your "options" as children of a scrolled window. Don't forget to set `wxRB_GROUP`.

The scrolled window itself can be a child of a wxStaticBox, so you can get the border+title effect.

Comment: okay sure. Can you please tell me how should I find selected button when user submits the form. Do I need to traverse through every wxRadioButton? For that I need to create a dynamic array as number of radiobuttons is not fixed.

Comment: Yes, you need to ask every wxRadioButton with its [GetValue() method](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_radio_button.html#a526055adf38d18b7fbf988d859f00d42). For the dynamic array, a `std::vector<wxRadioButton*>` (yes, pointers) may be enough.